# Wordcloud in R including characters “ and ”, how do I delete them?

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm trying to make a word cloud out of a Sherlock Holmes story, the problem is the top words are ” and “.

I can't delete them as other words with the `tm_map` function with the `removeWords` property. What I've tried is this:

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c('“'))
```

Comment: Maybe try the `removePunctuation` function if you don't want punctuation like quotation marks.

Comment: @MrFlick That was my thought too.  Looks like removePunctuation doesn't remove these special quotes even if you use ucp=TRUE.  A different approach would be necessary here I think.

Comment: I would use `gsub` and change `“` to regular quotes, if feasible for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like `removePunctuation` from the `tm` package.

```r
library(tm)
library(janeaustenr)

# With Punctuation
data("prideprejudice")
prideprejudice[30]

# Punctuation Removed
prideprejudice <- removePunctuation(prideprejudice)
prideprejudice[30]
```

You can also use the `tidytext` package. The `unnest_tokens` function will automatically strip punctuation. You probably also want to get rid of stop words, which you can do with something like this:

```r
library(tm)
library(tidytext)
library(janeaustenr)
library(dplyr)

data("prideprejudice")
data(stop_words)

prideprej_tibble <- tibble(text=prideprejudice)

prideprej_words <- prideprej_tibble %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)
```

See [here](https://www.tidytextmining.com/) for more.

Comment: Can you show that this method removes the special quote characters?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik See edit. Added reproducible examples for both methods.

Comment: This does not show how it removes the special quotes (`“` != `"`), sorry.